# Gdk Screen and add_provider_for_screen

Tags: gtk

What exactly is Gdk Screen represent?
My guess was that Screen represent whole display area of the pc and Window represent display area of certain application.
Then what is the meaning of adding provider to the screen in code shown below.I think i m interested in styling only current application window.

```
css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
css_provider.load_from_data(css.encode())
context = Gtk.StyleContext()

screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
context.add_provider_for_screen(screen, css_provider,
                                Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
```

> Adds a global style provider to screen, which will be used in style
> construction for all Gtk.StyleContexts under screen

this is in the documentation of add_provider_for_screen().
Am i not understanding What screen is properly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Gtk.screen is the system screen and it handle all the physical screens(multiple monitors). This is that there is one screen for all the monitors(or is the common case); with this in mind, monitors doesn't need to have the same dimensions and, once the application is running it cannot change the style by itself, so this is the screen job. This prevents the application to display annoying sizes along the screen.

So, since 5 pixels are not always 5 pixels, style is something that needs be managed by the screen and not by the window, and all of that without considering the color management.

Comment: what does " once the application is running it cannot change the style by itself" mean?

Comment: also adding styles to screen feels to me like style should be affecting other windows too, how does this work? i m not specifying anywhere which window to style but it is styling desired window. but how?

Comment: Gtk has a main function, this main function is instantiated by the application, and one instance doesn't affect the others